# How to plot points in 2D without restricting their apparent positions to pixel grid?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, rendering

Compare the two renderings of the same point in the following code (this is just a reduced example, I know I could just zoom in the scene, it's not an option in original code):

```
Manipulate[Row[{
   Graphics[Point[{0, x[t]}], PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.3}},
     Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 10],
   Graphics3D[Point[{0, x[t], 0}], 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.3}, All}, Boxed -> False, 
    ImageSize -> 10, ViewVector -> {0, 0, 10^4}]
   }], {t, 10, 100}, ControlPlacement -> Left, 
 Initialization :> (x[t_] = Abs@Sin[t]/t)]
```

The resulting two points animate like follows:

[image: animations for comparison]

Here's a magnified version of the above animation to better see what happens:

[image: magnified version]

You can see the point at left seems to move jerkily, while the one at right moves smoothly. After some time the left one stops moving, while the right one still does visibly move. This is due to antialiasing of *positions*, not just shape. 2D functions seem to round positions to integer screen coordinates, while 3D ones don't.

The second way with `Graphics3D` would be the best solution for me, but in some more complex 2D scenes the 3D engine takes too much time to render, making `Manipulate` unusable.

So my question is: is there any way to force 2D `Graphics` and functions like `ListPlot` antialias positions too, so that one didn't need to resort to 3D engine?

Comment: There is no difference. Both "vibrate" the same way. Try this to see it better `Manipulate[
 Row[{
   Graphics[
    {PointSize[Large], Point[{0, x[t]}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}}, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 50],
   Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point[{0, x[t], 0}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 1.1}, All}, Boxed -> False, 
    ImageSize -> 50, ViewVector -> {0, 0, 10^4}]
   }],
 {{t, .1, "time"}, .1, 100, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ContinuousAction -> True},
 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 
 Initialization :> (
   x[t_] := Abs@Sin[t]/t
   )
 ]`

Comment: You also defining a function use `=`. This should really be `=:`.

Comment: @Nasser of course you don't see any difference if you enlarge the points — see my parenthesized part of the first sentence. I wasn't talking about logical positions — my question is about _rasterization_, which does yield different results. To see the difference, use a screen magnifier (e.g. Qt's `pixeltool`) on my animation. As for function definition, why should it be a delayed assignment (I guess you mean `:=` not `=:`)? It doesn't make any real difference here, and in general it isn't useful to completely reevaluate an expression for each argument unless the expression is not idempotent.

Comment: Related question: [Graphics elements do not line up perfectly in exported PDFs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38745)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution, if there's no native support for this in Mathematica, is to implement manual supersampling. Here's an example function which could do it:

```
antialias[img_, size_, supersampling_: 5] := ImageResize[Image[Rasterize[img,
    RasterSize -> supersampling*size], ImageSize -> supersampling*size], size]
```

The steps here are

1. `Rasterize`, which renders the image as it should look, but in a higher resolution,
2. `Image`, which creates actual image in the requested size (which `Rasterize` doesn't do),
3. `ImageResize`, which downsamples, applying some low-pass filter to the supersampled image.

If we omit step 1, then in various `Plot`, `ListPlot` etc. we'll get wrong sizes of points and lines. `Rasterize` makes them look correct.

Now we can include this variant in the demo from the OP as follows (the point rendered by the new method is in the middle):

```
Manipulate[Row[{
   Graphics[Point[{0, x[t]}], PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.3}},
     Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 10],
   antialias[Graphics[Point[{0, x[t]}], PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.3}},
     Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 10], 10],
   Graphics3D[Point[{0, x[t], 0}], 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.3}, All}, Boxed -> False, 
    ImageSize -> 10, ViewVector -> {0, 0, 10^4}]
   }], {t, 10, 100}, ControlPlacement -> Left, 
 Initialization :> (
   x[t_] = Abs@Sin[t]/t;
   antialias[img_, size_, supersampling_: 5] := ImageResize[
     Image[Rasterize[img, RasterSize -> supersampling*size], 
      ImageSize -> supersampling*size], size]
   )]
```