# Choosing specific font variants

Tags: front-end, fonts, style

Many fonts come with several variants that can be accessed from most OS X applications.  Here's an example showing several variants of the [Latin Modern Roman](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/latin-modern) font.

[image]

(These variants in the screenshot are all displayed at 11 pt size, but their shapes/weights are *designed* to be used at the indicated sizes; hence the names "10 Regular", etc.)

You don't have to install a special font to try this though. Many fonts that come with the OS, such as Helvetica Neue on OS X, have them.

Using Format -> Show Fonts in Mathematica brings up a window where these variants can be chosen.  But choosing them has no effect.

**Question:** Is it at all possible to use these variants in Mathematica 10.3?

I am primarily interested in OS X, but answers for other operating systems are welcome too.

Comment: Why not to add OSX tag?

Comment: @garej I didn't add the tag because eventually I would want to ask the same about other systems too, so I'm interested in Windows/Linux answers as well.  I don't know if these should be separate from the OS X one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At present you cannot get these font variants on OS X because the `FontWeight` option only chooses between Regular and Bold.  This is a somewhat historical artifact from a time when only four font variants (Normal, Bold, Italic, and Bold Italic) needed to be resolved.

There is an additional issue that the `PrivateFontOptions` option `"FontPostScriptName"` does not work as intended on OS X.

We consider both of these issues to be bugs.

Comment: Can we get these variants on Windows, or maybe Linux? (I'm using OS X right now so I cannot try, but I am curious.)

Comment: Seeing that you work on the FE, maybe you can answer this: are the developers aware of the practical issues that coordinate rounding causes with PDF export, and how the elements of the exported graphics can be positioned quite differently in the PDF than what I saw in the notebook?  This is constantly giving me trouble when I make figures (especially when using the SciDraw package for complex figures).  Unfortunately it is quite difficult to create small examples that illustrate the problems well, and even harder to show why this is such a big deal during practical work. I assume you are ...

Comment: ... aware of the problems, but if not, maybe one day I should put in the time to write a convincing letter to support about this.  [Here's one example of the rounding problems.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38745/graphics-elements-do-not-line-up-perfectly-in-exported-pdfs)  Trouble comes in cases when using `Export` won't make rounding go away ... (usually with lots of `Inset`s, typical of [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) output).

Comment: To the best of my knowledge `FontWeight` option works better on Windows and Linux.  You should be able to access the variants on that platform.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't obvious that one must use `FontWeight`.  I'll try.

Comment: I am not aware of the rounding issues you mentioned.  It would be worth the time to get a bug filed.  The on-screen and PDF rendering share a good portion of the formatting and drawing path.  If both exhibit the same alignment bug, then the issue is probably early on.  If they don't, then the bug is probably in the specific code for that output.  Having a well-explained demonstration of the issue would really help.