# Mathematica to Microsoft Word to PDF workflow

Tags: graphics, pdf-format, display, office

Can anyone outline successful workflows for preparing equations and graphics in Mathematica, exporting (e.g. copy and paste) the results to MS Word and producing good looking results in a PDF?

In the past, at least, I've had problems (I guess, involving missing fonts), where PDFs that looked OK on the machine where I produced have substituted incorrect characters.

Unfortunately MS Word is an essential part of this workflow.

[Transfer graphics from Mathematica to Word without loss of quality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54708/36788) provides useful advice for graphics.

Comment: Do you know about [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org) and [pandoc](http://pandoc.org)?

Comment: @Louis - using LaTeX would certainly make many things easier.  Unfortunately MS Word is an essential part of this workflow for reasons of collaboration.

Comment: Well never mind check pandoc!

Comment: Windows or OS X?

Comment: I have to use Windows, and I'm quite constrained in terms of what other tools I can add to the mix (beyond Mathematica and Word).  As it's Windows XP, I'm limited to Mathematica 9 (despite paying for premier service)!

Comment: See my workflow here (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54708/transfer-graphics-from-mathematica-to-word-without-loss-of-quality).

Answer (score 3):

**For equations:** Copy as MathML, then paste into Word.  This will create a proper equation in Word.  Should work with Word versions that support the new-style equation editor, both on Windows and Mac.

**For graphics:** Use "Copy as PDF" on Mac.  I think the right way is "Copy as EMF" on Windows.

I would advise caution when copying and pasting graphics into Word on Mac.  Word is just not reliable.  It is safer to `Export` the graphics to PDF (not copy), then include them in Word.  Sometimes Word for Mac destroys the graphics (rasterizes at low resolution) when you save and reopen the file, so you want to have backups in this case ...

Comment: Copy as MathML and pasting into Word 2016 works great on Windows. I had no idea about, thank you.

Comment: @TimMayes Thanks, updated the post.