# How to Debug Error in PDF Export?

Tags: graphics, export

I have a complex graphic with text which exports correctly as a jpg or png file but if I export it as a PDF then some of the sloping letters are missing. How can I go about debugging it? For the sake of an example, I offer some code below, but the graph that results from this code exports correctly. So, I am also unable to reproduce the error in a simple setting. Non-error example:

```
test = Graphics[{ RGBColor[242/250, 101/250, 34/250, .7], 
  Disk[{0, 0}, .2], 
  Black, Table[Text["Abcderfghij", {0, 0}, {-1, 0}, {1, i}], {i, -1, 1, .1}], 
  Table[Text["Abcderfghij", {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, i}], {i, -1, 1, .1}] },
  ImageSize -> 257];

Export[fpath <> "test.pdf", test]
```

Comment: I think all Mathematica commands should have a Verbose->True option. But this is not the case...

Comment: SVG output by itself seems to work `Export["test2.svg", test]` so maybe the PDF reader cannot handle it as PDF should have embedded SVG unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround was to (1) export a large PNG file (which renders fine); (2) open it in Photoshop; (3) adjust to the desired dimensions and resolution in Photoshop; (4) save as PDF. Exporting a file in the dimensions of the final PDF, even if in high resolution, does not produce a smooth picture, I think that the problem is that sharpening artifacts get introduced. For adjusting `FontSize` and `ImageSize` compare [Transfer graphics from Mathematica to Word without loss of quality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54708/transfer-graphics-from-mathematica-to-word-without-loss-of-quality/234591#234591).