# How to set image DPI?

Tags: graphics, export

For publications usually images in TIFF format are required in high resolutions. Where can I change settings for images that are being saved (using RMB click "Save Graphic As..."), so I don't need to post process them in Illustrator?

Comment: Have a look at:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImageResolution.html

Comment: Just use the `Export` function to export to bitmap formats. It has a whole bunch of parameters that you can set to determine the image parameters.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/296/how-to-export-large-graphics

Comment: What platform are you on? I can see an Options button on my Mac system..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `ImageSize` and `ImageResolution` options can be a bit tricky sometimes, but this will usually work:

```
g = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]

cm = 72/2.54 (* centimetre *)

Export["figure.tiff", Show[g, ImageSize -> 10 cm], ImageResolution -> 300]
```

This will export an image 10 cm wide with 300 dpi resolution.

The important point was to use `ImageSize` inside `Show` and not directly in `Export`.

Note: you *must* use a command to export with these settings.  If you export using the GUI then you can't change these options.

Also, I recommend using a vector format such as PDF for publication, except for 3D graphics.