# How to set distance between ticks to 1cm

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

I have for example the following grid:

```
range = Range[0, 4, 0.5];
Graphics[Frame -> True, GridLines -> {range, range}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}, Ticks -> {Automatic}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

How can I plot a grid where the distance between axes numbers is 1 cm?

Comment: Centimeters are relative, not all screens have the same dpi.

Comment: If this is not possible at the screen, how can it be done in the printout.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(5442)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5442/121), [(77129)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77129/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to:

- Control the relationship between plot coordinates and the image size. This means that all settings that affect this must be set manually, and must not be left to chance
- Set the correct image size.

In Mathematica, there are plot coordinates, scaled coordinates and absolute coordinates.  Please read here:

- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/750/12 (actually everything you need is described there)

For this task we need to work with plot coordinates and absolute ones.  Absolute coordinates are given in printer's points.

Define the centimetre:

```
cm = 72/2.54 (* 72 points in an inch, 2.54 cm in an inch *)
```

First step: eliminate all sorts of margins and paddings, to make sure that the frame is precisely on the edge of the image:

```
range = Range[0, 4, 0.5];
g = Graphics[Frame -> True, GridLines -> {range, range}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}, Ticks -> {Automatic},
  ImageSize -> 8 cm,
  PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> None, ImageMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

It's clear that now the image size should be 8 cm, so we set it to that.  But the labels are cut off.

Next step: manually set the [`ImagePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) to leave enough room for ticks labels. This is specified in printer's points.  We need to increase the image size accrodingly.  I am lazy so I'll set the same padding on all sides.

```
range = Range[0, 4, 0.5];
g = Graphics[Frame -> True, GridLines -> {range, range}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}, Ticks -> {Automatic},
  ImageSize -> 8 cm + 2*15 (* allow for 15 pt ImagePadding on both sides *),
  PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> 15, ImageMargins -> 0]
```

[image]

Now export to PDF,

```
Export["grid.pdf", g]
```

and print the result. In the print settings make sure to set the scale to 100%.  Often the default is automatic, which tends to scale the document to fill the page.

Hint: Do use `Export`.  Do *not* use right click, Save As...  Read here: [Graphics elements do not line up perfectly in exported PDFs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38745/12)

If you need to display at a given size on a screen, you must do some measurements and discover the true pixel density ("dpi") of your screen.  Then scale the graphics accordingly using e.g. `Magnify[g, factor]`.

Comment: Great explanation ... thank you

Comment: @MichaelE2 Of course, thank you!

Comment: To be accurate, Mathematica, like nearly all software, uses [Postscript point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)#Desktop_publishing_point). TeX, which predates most desktop publishing software, uses printer's points, which are 0.9963 times smaller. I had to correct for this in MaTeX to match the two up.

Comment: You may also use the builtin unit functions. Define `cmToDpp = QuantityMagnitude@UnitConvert[Quantity[#, "Centimeters"], "DesktopPublishingPoints"] &`. Then `cmToDpp@8` and so on. (+1)