# Exporting graphics of precisely specified measurements for printing

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format, printing

None of the links bellow seem to answer the problem with printing graphics "scaled to the real world" anymore:

[real size image printing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5442/real-size-image-printing)

[exporting pdf with a precise page dimension in metric units rather than printer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77129/exporting-pdf-with-a-precise-page-dimension-in-metric-units-rather-than-printer)

[how to set distance between ticks to 1cm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133332/how-to-set-distance-between-ticks-to-1cm/133335#133335)

When I created a rectangle in MS Word (any version) and specify it to be 2cm x 3cm and then printed it (on many different printers) then guess what... if you measured the rectangle on the paper it was precisely 2cm x 3cm.

Why Mathematica is not able to do such a simple task? Few years old code (which probably worked at that time, not sure) does not work anymore. Furthermore you still had to give Mathematica data like `72`, `2.54`... and what to do with it to get the result correct like that can not be done automatically like in MS Word for example.

I adapted code from the third link to print circle of radius 2.75cm:

```
cm = 96/2.54*8/7.7;
range = Range[0, 4, 0.5];
g = Graphics[{Circle[{2, 2}, 2.75/2/2]}, Frame -> True, 
  GridLines -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}, PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}, 
  ImageSize -> 8 cm, PlotRangePadding -> None, ImagePadding -> None, 
  ImageMargins -> 0]
Export["grid.pdf", g]
```

I found out that instead of `72` I have to use (probably) `96` and still have to adjust it by another empirical constant `8/7.7` which was figured out from my first printed paper that was not the correct size.

**So is there a universal proper method of printing graphics objects "scaled to the real world" in Mathematica?**

Comment: To be specific, I mean this answer: [How to work always in WYSIWYG mode?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137746/1871)

Comment: A cheap solution is to create a rectangle: rect on screen and print it using "PrintSelection". Then measure the printed rectangle and scale the original rectangle so that the printed rectangle has the right size.