# How do I manage the Size and bits of my pictures?

Tags: plotting, graphics

How do I make pictures sharp looking when while not blowing them up in my screen in Mathematica ?

For example, I uploaded two pics. One with ImageSize -> 100

[image: ImageSize -> 100]

and one with  ImageSize -> 1000

```
 Graphics3D[{}, ImageSize -> 1000]
```

[image: ImageSize -> 1000]

You clearly see that the one with  ImageSize -> 1000 is larger and higher definition (sharper picture).

Question: How do I make pictures sharp looking when while not blowing them up in my screen in Mathematica ?

Comment: Please post the code with which you created the image.

Comment: The code is  added

Comment: Check out this answers:
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25493/21855
- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/310/21855
Besides this you could also export the graphics in another format that supports vector graphics eg. a PDF file.